# Bruce Banner needs to eat, but does the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Does the Hulk actually need to consume food, or is Bruce Banner's normal dietary intake enough? I'm asking because it seems transforming from the Hulk back to Bruce Banner with a half a cow in his stomach could be rough on the poor Doctor.

Comment: Didn't the Hulk once tried to eat one of Wolverine's legs?

Comment: @HNL Yes, in the Ultimate Hulk vs. Wolverine comic, although I believe he was interrupted by the arrival of She-Hulk, so he didn't follow through on his threat.

Comment: Hulk takes care of that before he becomes puny Banner. http://i.imgur.com/3kLpV.jpg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've always assumed that Hulk gets his energy from Gamma radiation inherent within him, not unlike Superman getting his energy from the sun. While he doesn't have an ongoing source of Gamma radiation it was my understanding there is enough energy within him that it doesn't need to be recharged.

This would be supported by a small sample of his blood infusing someone else with similar powers (She-hulk).

While I don't think Hulk needs to eat, I think he can eat, at least in the Ultimate universe. I seem to recall in Ultimate Hulk vs Wolverine, when he is confronted in Tibet he is eating a chicken leg or something.

In Marvel zombies, Hulk ate and when he changed back into Bruce Banner the food inside him caused problems, with it falling out of his stomach. Although this greatly interested Zombie Thor.

On the Hulk TV show, he was [shown to eat](http://images.yuku.com/image/pjpeg/22026d25e11df2bd85e7f994800aaf8c3180421a.pjpg)

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't need food. Any damage caused to his body from lack of food/starvation is taken care of by his healing factor. Although Banner could starve to death, just before he does he would black out from lack of caloric energy and turn into the Hulk.