# What is Superman's metabolic rate?

Tags: dc, superman

Is it possible to calculate (or approximate in a reasonably scientifically credible way) the [metabolic rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate) of Superman (be it in his prime, or at least at when he still keeps his ability to fool anyone into thinking he's simply a reporter)?

Is there by any chance his metabolic rate is proportional to the amount of sunlight he receives?

Comment: What is your actual question? At the moment you just seem to have three or four vaguely-related sentences smooshed together.

Comment: The phrase "what is your thought on this?" is kind of a red-flag to me; this site is meant for questions with [concrete answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and this is more of [an opening for a discussion.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) If you can rephrase it to be more conclusively answered, you may have better luck.  I.e., "Can Superman exist solely on Solar Energy, or is there canon info indicating his additional metabolic needs?" or something similar; it restricts the scope to the specific information you are seeking.

Comment: And come to that, what is a metabolism rate? What’s *your* metabolism rate?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite hi there I had heed your comment/advise and edited my question, metabolism is a biological process unique to cellular organism to convert "yummy" into "I'm letting loose!" and erm... my metabolism rate is sligthly lower than 2000 calories a day because typing is really tiring. good day

Comment: Since the question is closed, I'll answer here. Its complicated, and exact numbers can't be given, but His calorie intake via sunlight, completely overshadows (pun intended) his resting and acting calorie needs in most situations by some absurdly high number. His metabolism allows a near perfect conversion of sunlight into energy, with no need for moderation.

Comment: Also see the answer to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37429/does-superman-need-to-eat

Comment: @cde I wants to believe superman is more than just a solar cell bank which(pun?) throws a volley of punches to anyone or anything that do not agrees with him, if I'm a abandoned kryptonian I'll be like "no high five please! people are flying"

Comment: I would like to delete this question due to the overwhelming response within 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superman doesn't need solar energy to *survive*.
There are several instances of him not being in contact with sunlight and living, but without his powers.
Solar power only gives him his immense strength (and the ability to fly and freeze breath and what not). For example, in the Justice League episode, "Hereafter", he's on earth in a different time. That is the time when the sun has gotten extinguished. We see him becoming all human, he even survives wolves, drives a car, as humans do.
So basically, superman is like a human that gets supercharged with solar radiation.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a great new idea? Supersolarman, Solarsuperman, The man of steel powered by light? That would be a great series. (But in the vast DC universe I guess something like this already exists)

Comment: @Julian I guess someone would make a suit or something with highly efficient solar panels on it, and somehow concentrate the energy into environmental friendly fuel for the suit. Something like Solar-man! :D
I know of no such hero in DC/Marvel universe yet

Comment: And then have his companion, a wind and water powered unicorn who can shoot from his horn and poops rainbows. 
Sorry for the spam :)

Comment: interesting a walking/flying solar panel with a lot of justice and now is looking for a sidekick who or whatever that is. good day

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first to wonder about Superman's "super-metabolism". In fact, the issue was poked fun at during the first episode to [Lois & Clark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_%26_Clark:_The_New_Adventures_of_Superman).

Lois arrives at Clark's apartment to pick him up for work, and catches him dressed in nothing but a towel. While waiting for him to get dressed, she notices that his fridge is full of nothing but junk food and makes the following observation:

> **LOIS:** Explain something to me.
>
> **CLARK:** What do you mean?
>
> **LOIS:** Um... well, you eat like an eight-year-old, yet you look like
>   Mr. Hardbody. What's your secret, and can I have it?
>
> **CLARK:** (looks perplexed, shrugs)
>
> **LOIS:** (sighs, heads towards door) We'd better go.
>
> **CLARK:** (smirks at the underlying compliment)

Comment: agreed however based on the extract of conversation between the two I think either the fridge and its content are simply a disguise and in fact he might not need food at all or in my humble opinion his >100% efficiency metabolism rate only second to matter-antimatter propulsion engine(stuff of sci-fi).

Comment: You might be right, but IIRC he is shown actually eating some of the junk food in the same episode. Also, in a later episode, his parents made a joke about how much it took to keep him fed as a teenager.